# How to implement grapple hook and swing

Tags: unity, 2d, physics, game-mechanics, rope-physics

I'm trying to make a retro style grapple hook / swing system that has a constant speed and is not based on real-life physics. Like the one in Axiom Verge, Bionic Commando (NES) and Super Metroid.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and how have your approaches fallen short of what you want? [I see there are lots of tutorials about how to make grappling hook mechanics](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+geappling+hook+tutorial&ia=web) — what should our answers do differently than what's been covered in these resources already?

Comment: @DMGregory HI! So I've been trying to use sin and cos to get the swing movement. But I have no clue on getting the player to swing correctly relevant to the pivot point. Seems like all the tutorials are using hingeJoints, or distantJoints that depend on real-life physics I posted the code above.

Comment: How does the current behavior differ from what you'd deem "correct"? Note that physics functions can be used as the basis for non-real-life physics gameplay: it all depends on how you drive them. Calculate cartoony forces/velocities, get cartoony game feel, even if you're letting the physics engine do the heavy lifting under the hood.

Comment: @DMGregory It moves correctly, I just cant figure out how to adjust the size of the movement based on where the player is relevant to the  pivot point (target) Example the farther away from the pivot point, the larger the swing, the close to pivot point, the smaller. With built in Unity physics it's hard to get constant velocity. I added a shot of Bionic commando above to better show what I mean.

Comment: @DMGregory I figured it out. I did so without Unity's physics functions.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out! This works without any of Unity's built-in physics! This gets concomitant movement like in retro games.

```
    public float speed = 1f;

    public Transform hookPoint;
    public float sinTime;

    public float angle = 0;
    public Vector2 velocity;

    public float direction;
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    public Texture2D texture2D;

    void Start()
    {
        lineRenderer.positionCount = 2;
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, hookPoint.position);

        lineRenderer.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", texture2D);
        SetStartingAngle();

    }

    private void SetStartingAngle()
    {
        float dx = transform.position.x - hookPoint.position.x;
        float dy = transform.position.y - hookPoint.position.y;

        angle = Mathf.Atan2(dy, dx) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        if (angle < 0)
            angle += 360;

        sinTime = (angle * 2) / 100;

        //Sets starting direction
        if (angle > 270)
            direction = -1;
        else
            direction = 1;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
        {
            if (radius == 0)
            {
                radius = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, hookPoint.position);
            }

            angle = (sinTime / 2 * 100);
            velocity.x = Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * radius;

            //Add hookPoint Y pos to center sinWave
            velocity.y = (Mathf.Sin(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * radius) +
            hookPoint.position.y;

            transform.position = velocity;
            sinTime += (speed * Time.deltaTime) * direction;

            //Ping-pongs to move in 1/2 circle
            if (angle >= 359)
                direction = -1;
            else if (angle < 180)
                direction = 1;

            //Updates line render
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, hookPoint.position);
        }
        else
        {
            radius = 0;
        }

    }
}
```